# How do I input these statements into a truth table generator?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I have tried inputting my problems into several truth table solvers. I keep getting error messages.

Which solver should I use and how do I change my statements on the homework in order to prevent getting errors?

Here are examples of the problems in my homework.

```
 P->s
 P v Q
 Q -> R         /..S v R
```

```
 R & S
 S -> P         /..P
```

```
 (P v Q)->R
 Q              /..R
```

I am using the textbook Critical Thinking Moore and Parker 11e.

Answer (score 2):

In the Stanford [Truth Table Generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) I used the following input strings to generate the three truth tables you presented as examples.

> ((P->S)&&(PvQ)&&(Q->R))->(SvR)
>
> ((R&&S)&&S)->(P)
>
> (((PvQ)->R)&&(Q))->(R)

Each truth table generator will have its own input syntax so you will have to be careful to follow that.

Regardless, take each premise and surround it with parentheses and then "and" them together. In this way the premises form a conjunction of statements. Surround that conjunction of statements in parentheses. Then put in a conditional symbol. Finally add the conclusion in parentheses.

There may be other truth table generators worth trying besides this one. It is just an example of one that appeared after a search for such tools.

---

Truth Table Generator, Stanford http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/

Answer (score 1):

There are three different arguments.

The first one has four propositional variables : **P, Q, R, S**. Thus, we need four initial columns for them; then three more columns (one for each premise) and a final one for the conclusion.

Thus, **8** columns in total.

For the number of rows, the formula is **2 raised n**, where **n** is the number of propositional variables. For **n=4**, we need **16** rows.

---

The other two have only three propositional variables and are simpler.

---

See [Truth Tables method](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Method_of_Truth_Tables).